# The type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RgbColorClass' has no constructors defined

Tags: arcobjects, c#

Trying to create a simple line symbol. 
But getting an error: "The type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.RgbColorClass' has no constructors defined"

```c#
public override void OnClick()
    {
        IDocument pdoc = m_application.Document;
        IMxDocument pmxdoc = (IMxDocument)pdoc;
        IActiveView pactive = pmxdoc.ActiveView;
        IRgbColor rgbColorCls = new RgbColorClass();
        rgbColorCls.Red = 138;
        rgbColorCls.Green = 151;
        rgbColorCls.Blue = 255;
        ISimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
        simpleLineSymbol.Color = rgbColorCls;            
    }
```

Comment: I don't program in c# so may be what I am suggesting is incorrect but in VB I would not have put () after RgbColorClass.

Comment: Your syntax is correct according to the [Create RGBColor Snippet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#13b0e444-9c22-4abf-8258-0443db203952.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Got this fixed. For those facing similar issue: expand the "References", find the ESRI.ArcGIS.Display reference. Right click it and select properties, and change "Embed Interop Types" to false.

Comment: Yep, that's a trap for young players... this one did my head in for a few days. This is on the borderline between GIS.SE and StackOverflow as it's a Visual Studio build problem and not an ArcObjects issue. While it's here though it's worth a +1, no doubt someone else will have the same problem and search this site.

Comment: Thanks - I had this problem when debugging some existing project and had to adopt the code to run against a different version of ArcMap - then I got all these weird errors when I did a clone of the project from Git.  This helped alleviate the head scratching!!